# help with javascript syntax for settimeout function statement

Tags: javascript

The syntax for the setTimeout function in javascript code below is correct

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('test').style.display='none'",3000);
```

I want to substitute the var testdiv to shorten the code

```
testdiv = document.getElementById('test');
```

But when I substitute the var testdiv into the setTimeout call, it does not work with the syntax that I have.

```
setTimeout("testdiv.style.display='none'",3000); //does not work with wrapping dblquotes.

setTimeout(testdiv.style.display='none',3000); //does not work either.
```

What is the correct syntax for writing this statement using the short cut?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead of a string.

```
setTimeout(function() { testdiv.style.display='none'; }, 3000);
```